# mongodb - $lookup not working with $project

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get the list of registered user from `mongodb collection`. and in my user's list i have stored some other details which belongs to another collection. like Country, State, City

I am using `mongodb version 3.2` and  [aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) methods to get this my users list.

In my users list i want to show the country name, state name, and city name So I used `$lookup` to join those collection to get name's.

This is just an example to take Country, State and City, it could be any  type of category data i just want to implement joining collection in one query.

Here is what i have tried so far:

1. This is my first [WHERE CONDITION TO GET NAME'S](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=96f78f99eb58778b00e57e9f6f04d547) - I get all name's.
2. But Now i also want to get only few columns from the each document so i used `$project`

   ```
   "$project": {
       "full_name": 1,
       "email": 1,
       "mobile": 1,
       "country": 1,
       "state": 1,
       "city": 1
    }
   ```

Second [WHERE CONDITION](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=3547a34e2c5153cf4062fef7c1540f58) -  after adding
`$project` to my where condition it only gives me those few columns not
getting **country_name, state_name and city_name**

Please tell me why [my query](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=3547a34e2c5153cf4062fef7c1540f58) is not giving the **country_name, state_name and city_name** after using `$project`.

```
[
   {
      "$match":{
         "status":{
            "$ne":2
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"countries",
         "localField":"country",
         "foreignField":"id",
         "as":"country_det"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"states",
         "localField":"state",
         "foreignField":"id",
         "as":"state_det"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup":{
         "from":"cities",
         "localField":"city",
         "foreignField":"id",
         "as":"city_det"
      }
   },
   {
      "$limit":10
   },
   {
      "$skip":0
   },
   {
      "$project":{
         "full_name":1,
         "email":1,
         "mobile":1,
         "country":1,
         "state":1,
         "city":1
      }
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$project doesn't work as WHERE condition, it doesn't filter the records.
It works as mapper. (It transforms each record as specified, that is why it is named 'project').

In your case. This pipeline stage:

```js
"$project":{
         "full_name":1,
         "email":1,
         "mobile":1,
         "country":1,
         "state":1,
         "city":1
      }
```

Literally says. Take the following fields: full_name, email etc and omit any other fields.
Please check out [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project).

If you need to do the 2nd WHERE please use another $match stage for it.

Also $lookup operator pushes the matching records to an array even if it is 1:1 relation.
So you might need to do

```
{$unwind: "$country_det"}
```

after the $lookup and same for state and city to have objects (not arrays of one element).

And finally if you want the resulting records to have properties named country_name, state_name and city_name you indeed need $project stage like this:

```js
"$project":{
         "full_name":1,
         "email":1,
         "mobile":1,  
         "country":1,
         "state":1,
         "city":1,
         "country_name": "$country_det.path.to.country_name",
         "state_name": "$state_det.path.to.state_name",
         "city_name": "$city_det.path.to.city_name"  
      }
```

Here is [the resulting query](http://jsbin.com/hiveyeyibo/1/edit?js). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Antonio... This worked for me but i'm not done yet. actually i also need to set search by country_name,state_name and city_name within the same query. so i just put some code in `$match` which is like -  `$country_det.country_name: "xyz"`. but it shows bad query error.. how can i do that?

Comment: @ShailParas please provide the query you have now and the error that is thrown.

Comment: Here is [Query](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=f831f5665ae1d84bfe81b8c908bd87e7) and Error is : `Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message 'localhost:27017: bad query: BadValue: unknown top level operator: $country_det.country' in D:\xampp\htdocs\admin\ajax\ssp.customized.class.php:225
Stack trace`

Comment: @ShailParas Please checkout the docs. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex
Inside youre $match, field names like country_det.country should not have '$' prefix, but the operator name $regex and $options should have it. Also there is no 'flags' operator. It should be $options: 'i' instead. Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually i'm using php so i just used this function `new MongoRegex("/".$request['search']['value']."/i")`.. to create regex object and it gives me `MongoRegex Object
                                        (
                                            [regex] => Andhra
                                            [flags] => i
                                        )` but i also tried as u suggested but that gives  result as null

Comment: @ShailParas did you try to simplify the regex to something like ".*" (matches everything)? Does it work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135365/discussion-between-shail-paras-and-antonio-narkevich).